# Update subset of fields with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**How can I update a MongoDB document with Mongoose when only a subset of its fields are specified? (i.e. update the specified fields, but leave any other existing fields unchanged)**

In the following route handler, the user can choose which fields to provide. The following works, but using the `if` statements does not feel particularly great. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
    // Get the user properties from the request body
    const { email, firstname, lastname} = req.body;

    // Decide what fields to update
    const fieldsToUpdate = {
        updatedAt: Date.now(),
    };
    if(email)       fieldsToUpdate.email = email;
    if(firstname)   fieldsToUpdate.firstname = firstname;
    if(lastname)    fieldsToUpdate.lastname = lastname;

    // Update the user object in the db
    const userUpdated = await User
        .findByIdAndUpdate(
            userId,
            fieldsToUpdate,
            {
                new: true,
                runValidators: true,
            }
        );
```

I have tried a different approach using `email: email` but if a field is undefined or null, Mongoose will put `null` in the database instead of leaving the field unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper method like this:

```
const filterObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el) && (typeof obj[el] === "boolean" || obj[el]))
      newObj[el] = obj[el];
  });
  return newObj;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
  let filteredBody = filterObj(req.body, "email", "firstname", "lastname");
  filteredBody.updatedAt = Date.now();

  // Update the user object in the db
  const userUpdated = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, filteredBody, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I assume that `filterObj.updatedAt` is meant to be `filteredBody.updated at`? If so, can you fix that please, so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: If I wanted to use this helper function in multiple controllers, where would be a good place to put it? (i.e. its not a route, not a controller, not a middleware, not a model, etc - where does it go?)

Comment: @Ben the best place to put this method is in a util file.

Comment: @Ben in your code updatedAt was not in req.body, so that was an exception.
If you put the updatedAt to the req.body, you can also pass it to the helper method like this: ` let filteredBody = filterObj(req.body, "email", "firstname", "lastname","updatedAt");`

Comment: That's not what I mean. `filterObj.updatedAt` in line 2 of your second code example needs to be `filteredBody.updatedAt`, since you pass `filteredBody` to `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Comment: @Ben yes you are right, I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: I just noticed that this won't work with **boolean** data that is **false**, i.e. if I send a JSON request with body `"isActive": false` and the value was previously `true`, then it won't update the value - because the helper function will not include `isActive` in the `filteredBody`.

Comment: @Ben I updated the filterObj  method to handle boolean. Can you try please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203320/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-ben).