# Don't overwrite value in mongo if new value is null

Tags: node.js, mongoose

when doing mongoose with node i can update a document in mongo with..

```
      const account = await userModel
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          { 'shared.email': email },
          {
          $set: {
            'shared.username': req.body.username,
             ...
            'shared.country': req.body.country,
            'shared.dob': dob,
            },
          },
          {
            new: true,
          }
        )
        .exec();
```

and `req.body.username` is `null` or `''` and `shared.username` already in mongo  is `James` 
is there anyway to keep the username `James` and not overwrite it with `null` or `''`?

The userModel Schema is...

```
const userSchema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      confirmationCode: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
      confirmationSentAt: { type: Date },
      confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
    password: {
      hash: { type: String },
      resetCode: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
      sentAt: { type: Date },
    },
    shared: {
      avatarId: { type: String },
      bio: { type: String },
      country: { type: String },
      dob: { type: Date },
      email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
      fullName: { type: String },
      gender: { type: String },
      language: { type: String, default: 'en' },
      location: { type: String },
      loggedIn: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      username: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
      warningMessage: { type: String, default: 'verify' },
      webSite: { type: String },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59094214/11717458

Comment: no it's not about a sub-document it's about how to retain the original value when the new value is null, And it's specific to Mongoose and Node.js, its not related mongo and java for instance

Comment: Can you give sample request body?

Comment: As I stated `req.body.username` is `null` or `''`

Comment: Can you add User model code to the question?

Comment: Bill I tried to find some generic solution, but I couldn't find yet, but I have a working simple answer below, can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  exclude the fields with falsy values, and send this filtered object to the update query.

```js
  const { email, username, country } = req.body;

  let filteredBody = {};

  if (username) {
    filteredBody["shared.username"] = username;
  }

  if (country) {
    filteredBody["shared.country"] = country;
  }

  console.log(filteredBody);

  const account = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "shared.email": email },
    filteredBody,
    {
      new: true
    }
  );
```

Test:

Let's say we have this existing user in our collection.

```
{
    "_id": "5df24ed1ec018d37785c23bd",
    "shared": {
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "username": "user1",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

When we send a request body like this:

```
{
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "username": "",
        "country": "England"
}
```

The username field will not be updated, but the country will be updated like this:

```
{
    "shared": {
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "username": "user1",
        "country": "England"
    },
    "_id": "5df24ed1ec018d37785c23bd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Pass all you need to update in all cases to setData. And append username if available
const setData = {
        'shared.country': req.body.country,
        'shared.dob': dob,
        },
}

if(req.body.username){
  setData['shared.username'] = req.body.username;
}


const account = await userModel
    .findOneAndUpdate(
      { 'shared.email': email },
      {
      $set: setData,
      {
        new: true,
      }
    )
    .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected behavior of Mongoose is to accept "null" even if you specified a type for the field.

So, if you want to reject a "null" value, you have two options :

Option 1. In your schema, add "required: true" to the field. It will work also for "undefined" value and empty strings.

Option 2. In your function, add an if statement which will check the value before updating.