# Express Handling empty req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

What is the best way to handle empty or undefined **req.body** currently i have an if statement that will check if the req.body is true or undefined or has a length less than 0

Is there a better way to do that?
Is the way am doing it wrong ?

code sample:

`const location = req.body.location;`

`if (location === undefined || !location || location.length < 0)`

Comment: Does  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59094214/11717458) answer your question?

Comment: I am just curios, why would you want to check if the request.body is empty, and then  in your sample code you are looking for the location key in the req body. 
could it be you are trying to do a validation? In that case there are validation packages such as [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) that you could use to check if a key exists in the req body

Comment: Oh okay perfect that's thanks. I just needed to ensure I have a valid value before using mongo to query a database based on that location value but yeah I will look into the validation module

Answer (score 2):

Just Check like this, it will check **all the condition** whether it is `undefined`, `null` or it contains the `location key` or not including the `length`

```
if(req.body && req.body.location){
    const location = req.body.location
}
```

**OR**

```
const location = (req.body && req.body.location) ? req.body.location : '' ;

if (location){
    // rest code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can combine the [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) and [ES6 Destructuring assignment with default Value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```
const { location = [] } = req.body || {};

if (location.length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good case for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Similar to Narendra's answer, you could write..

```
if (req?.body?.location) {
    const location = req.body.location;
}
```

This would check for undefined on each of the properties, thus not crashing your app when one of the properties is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

if you need request validation in general i can highly recommend the [joi plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to you. so you can set location as a required parameter see at the [joi-docs](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.8)